# How to use latest npm on Azure Mobile Service deployment

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

The Azure Mobile Service image that I am using currently is locked down to npm version 1.2.30. There are latest npm version installed on the image(under ...\Program Files(x86)\npm). But npm is locked down to the version 1.2.30 due to the reason that it was installed with node.js(under ...\Program Files(x86)\nodejs) AND the path always looks under \nodejs\ folder first and uses it.

This is causing me problem in using some npm packages (including googleapis) on deployment. The errors appear while installing googleapis are bugs in older version of npm and are resolved in latest.

The simplest solution is to delete the 'npm' file and 'npm.cmd' file under ...\Program Files(x86)\nodejs\ folder so that the npm is read from ..\Program Files(x86)\npm\ folder. But i get access denied errors while trying to access these files. I am accessing the mobile service image through Kudu interface.

Is there are work-around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For upgrading npm, you can follow the instructions from David Ebbo on this forum post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/068ef026-f80d-4bf8-9f40-5d1af33a1024/git-deployment-fails-with-npm-error-when-resolving-a-package-version-containing-a-?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview