# Compile azure mobileservice to newer version of nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services, node-gyp

I have an azure mobile app that is consumed by a Cordova app - this azure mobile app is built in node.js and is responsible for managing the push notifications for this Cordova app.
In this node app, I use [mobileservices-sqlserver](https://github.com/azure/mobileservice-sqlserver/) to register in the database the devices that will receive the push notifications, and I am having problems with this module compilation in node version 6.1.9 - actually any version higher than 0.8x.

Can I pre-compile this [mobileservices-sqlserver](https://github.com/azure/mobileservice-sqlserver/) to a newer node version, maybe using node-gyp? I couldnt find any instructions on how to do that.
Sorry if that is silly question, but I'm really new to node.js.

I've seen some similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065987/how-to-use-latest-npm-on-azure-mobile-service-deployment), but I'm not sure if it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an old Mobile Services service? If so, check out the [Mobile Apps Compatibility NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-mobile-apps-compatibility), which replaces mobileservices-sqlserver with the [msnodesqlv8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8) and will allow your service to work with modern versions of Express and Node.js.

If this is already a more modern Mobile App service, see also the [mssql NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) for SQL Server data access.